# Как задать стили в данном случае?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как задать стили для label. Когда чекбокс с галочкой

```
<label for="id" /><input type="checkbox" id="id" checked />
```

Comment: При помощи js и проверки состояния

Comment: Переставь их местами, а потом задавай.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте местами и используйте `+`:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="id" checked /><label for="id">Тык</label>
```

**P.S:** можно было-бы использовать `has`, но к [сожалению](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has).